# Supporting a minimum width on a website

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

How do I ensure that my app only renders on a minimum screen width of 1300 pixels. Anything less than that should redirect the user to a fixed web page, something like a 404. This is a React app and I'm using a standard root div to render components inside a index.html.

Comment: Check the screen width on page load, and if it is less than 1300 pixels, then do the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using reactjs, you can try this out.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const width = screen.width;
  if (width > 1300) {
    render((
      <SomeComponent />
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
  }
  else {
    render((
      <div>404 not found </div>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Can this be modified to redirect the user to another page?

Comment: I haven't tried it but i think `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` in the else part will work as suggested by Alfred Xing

Answer (score 1):

You can check the screen width on load (either in your root component's constructor or `componentDidMount`, then redirect them if it's less than 1300:

```
var width = screen.width;
if (width < 1300) window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```